# Show image and text together inside a fragment and a subfragment of SlidingTabLayout (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have an Activity and 4 fragments inside it.
In the 4th fragment there are 2 sub fragments.
I'm using Google's SlidingTabLayout to show icons/text inside the tabs. I've handled the case to show icons or text inside the tabs. However i'm not able to make them work together.

```
F1 F2 F3 F4 (these tabs contain only images) <--this works fine
F1 F2 F3 F4(these tabs contain only text) <--this works fine

However, the below doesn't work. What can i do to handle this scenario?
  F1   F2   F3   F4 <--- Tab with icon
               SF1 SF2 <---- Tab with text
```

Code is as follows. 
This is how i display the image

```
 public void populateTabStripImage() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();
        View tabView = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, mTabStrip,
                    false);

            ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_icon);
            iconImageView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt((String) adapter.getPageTitle(i))));

            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView, layoutParams);
        }
    }
```

This is how i show text

```
private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the codes how you add text/icon to tab

Comment: have added the code.

Comment: Have you called `setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId)` that is method in `SlidingTabLayout` class to make your custom tab?

Comment: Yes. The class is untouched. The 'populateTabStripImage' is the only change that i've made.